# Is every commutative ring without non trivial idempotent ,local?

Tags: ideals, idempotents, local-rings

Is every commutative ring without non trivial idempotent ,local?
I know that every local ring doesn't contain nontrivial idempotent because the number of maximal ideals in R is equal to the sum of maximals in S and T where R=ST.
I thought since the ring doesn't contain nontrivial idempotent it can not be the direct product of two rings and each factor contains a maximal ideal so perhaps there us just one...

Comment: What is wrong with $\mathbb Z$ as an example. It has no non-trivial idempotent, but isn't local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for example any non-local domain is a counterexample.

For a non-domain example, an interesting one is $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-1)$ lacks nontrivial idempotents, but has distinct maximal ideals.

You can find this and several more examples [using this search at DaRT](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/commsearch/commresults/?has=58&lacks=4).